# I want to select all records from one dataframe where its value exists/not exists in another dataframe. How to do this using pyspark dataframes?

Tags: python, pyspark, semi-join

I have the two pyspark dataframes. 
I want to select all records from voutdf where its "hash" does not exist in vindf.tx_hash

How to do this using pyspark dataframe.? 
I tried a semi join but I am ending up with out of memory errors.

```
voutdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(voutRDD,["hash", "value","n","pubkey"])

vindf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vinRDD,["txid", "tx_hash","vout"])
```

Comment: I think you should use left-semi join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `left-anti` join:

```
df = voutdf.join(vindf.withColumnRenamed("tx_hash", "hash"), "hash", 'left_anti')
```

**left-anti join:**

It takes all rows from the left dataset that don't have their matching in the right dataset.

Comment: thanks Adam, just to confirm would  that be the equivalent of                           select * from voutdf where hash not in (select tx_hash from vindf)

Comment: Thanks a ton, Adam. Also to get the voutdf records where hash is in (select tx_hash from vindf)    would left_semi be ok? thanks                                                                                                           df = voutdf.join(vindf.withColumnRenamed("tx_hash", "hash"), "hash", 'left_semi')

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also register these two DataFrames as a temptable, and run SQL queries, if you are more familiar with that:
`df.registerTempTable("voutdf")`
`df.registerTempTable("vindf")`
`spark.sql("select * from voutdf where hash not in (select tx_hash from vindf)")`

Comment: I get error when I try to run it in sql form. maybe I am missing some relevant imports. is this the right way to call it?    sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sess = SparkSession(sc)                                                                               sess.sql("select * from voutdf where hash not in (select tx_hash from vindf)")

Comment: 19/12/04 14:56:54 WARN metadata.Hive: Failed to register all functions.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy